# AWS Using Lambda to Get S3 Object

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have put together an AWS API Gateway (HTTP) that triggers a lambda function. The lambda function gets an object from an S3 bucket. I've followed the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_s3_code_examples.html) from AWS, and I'm getting the objects body contents successfully but the PDF is coming through corrupted.

I have also reviewed [this post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/handling-binary-data-using-amazon-api-gateway-http-apis/) on AWS, but for some reason when I add `isBase64Encoded: true` the response returns as `500` and no detail gets logged to CloudWatch.

```
const getSupportingDocs = async (doc_id) => {
    try {

        const streamToString = (stream) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const chunks = [];
                stream.on("data", (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
                stream.on("error", reject);
                stream.on("end", () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString("utf8")));
            });

        const command = new GetObjectCommand({
            Bucket: "deq-waterlink-at",
            Key: doc_id,
        });

        const { Body } = await s3Client.send(command);
        //const { Body } = await s3Client.send(command).promise(); -> tried & nothing happened
        const bodyContents = await streamToString(Body);
        //console.log(bodyContents);
        return bodyContents;
    }

    catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR DOWNLOADING: ", err);
    }
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    console.log("EVENT: ", event);
    let response;

    try {
        if (event.queryStringParameters) {
            let key = event.queryStringParameters['doc-id'];
            let doc = await getSupportingDocs(`interactiveMap/${key}`);
            response ={
                "statusCode":200,
                "body":  JSON.stringify(doc),
                /*"isBase64Encoded": true, --> Results in an Internal Server Error*/
                "headers": {"content-type": "application/pdf"}
            };
        }
        else {
            response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify('No Document ID included'),
            };
        }
        return response;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", err);
    }
};
```

**UPDATE:**
After following the suggestion by Daniel Seichter below I was able to get the download triggered but I get an error message when trying to open the PDF that the file is damaged and cannot be repaired. If I removed the `JSON.stringify` around `doc` that file downloads but is blank.

I can directly download the file from S3 and it is not corrupted so something is happening in the download process.

I can log the response that the function generates and get the response below, but the browser returns a `500` response.

```
2022-08-03T21:56:12.163Z    9bd65c5c-6742-45a3-a6ef-6f314e4efa89    INFO    RESPONSE:  {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/pdf' },
  isBase64Encoded: true,
  body: '"%PDF-1.7\\n\\n4 0 obj\\n(Identity)\\nendobj\\n5 0 obj\\n(Adobe)\\nendobj\\n8 0 obj\\n<<\\n/Filter /FlateDecode\\n/Length 35942\\n/Length1 67496\\n/Type /Stream\\n>>\\nstream\\nx��\\u0007X\\u0014��?~�ݙ��.\\u001d�]\\u0016\\u0010\\\\p\\u0017V���bÂ�\\u00114(\\b(��J�+D�5�\\u0016M��ILL̛\\u00045�E\\r��Ę^Mb��f�2�;wv�\\u0012�����<�����a>s��{��{Ν\\u0001�\\u0000�\\u0019�\\u0003O^Ѱ!m�[;\\u0000\\u0016F\\u0001D?6$/\x7F0��\\u000b\\u00006���z\\f)\\u001c]t��u\\u0014�\x7F\\u0004(=2�h\\\\΢w�g\\u0003�܎�l\\u001f]�Lm�d�\\t\\u0000�\\"�/�&odI�O��\\u0000BN\\u0001�\'*�*�\\u0003NNa\\u0001�^�2\'+�4Yg�x�\\u0006�\\u0017�g�S���~�=U�Ma}�ߦU4z!\\flH\\u000f�\\u0001ô���\\u0018@�G\\u0000}~��������X�\\b�O��\\u0004c��[��a<���i^����\\u0000�\\u0004��ٙ��\\u0015k�.l\x7F\\n��:UW1�+�Q���\\u000f`yk]uSE��\\\\\\u000bDY���Y\\u0015uպ��4\\u0001��\\u0007к���M�yp\\u001c`�)Z��P��\\u001b��\\u0001���y��K�xၭ������B�\\u0000�xxf�\\u001f�����s�w��> �ǲ\\"0�?�9A-�\\u0005�eb�l�\\u0003rM\\u0017\\u001d�i��7C\\u001f`�\\u0004\\u0006\\f��\\tȵY���\\u0014�[�\\u001c\\u0002\\u001e\\u0004�vލU����68��\\u00020j�cy�c�m��y�:�r�>8��j\\u0005<�q�\\u001eR)�,��#V w��V��hO�\\u0015\\u0002$a\\u001b�%��\\u001dp��+���o�W���wa\\u0016�\\u000f\\u001e�t�\\f<��a�b;\\u001c����\\u0007�(\\u0016�4��I�P.���p8�܈y��\\u0011����wE\\u000e�=\\nu|\\u0013$*Z�A�&*!��\\r~\\u0015��\\u000f�\\u0004��7�N�q(��\\u0004�\\u0010J�\\np��=�\\u0013y���,�w\\nsa\'M���w�t�/|�I��އ�큻i��\\u001dH�\'@\\u0004�\\u0006=��\\u0018�\x7F|p/�f�Z��������\\u001e8��q��z\\\\=�\\u001eW������q��z\\\\=����vp\\b�����۾\\u0004�\\u000b�|$l���z�\\u0001����\\f���\\u0000���a;�;,��5c�tخX�y{��?\\u0001^^��r�L��\\txŢϻ��)�\\u0003r��`�\\u0013A�~3\\\\=�\\u001eW��\\u001d�\\u001e^��<�<��˺z�� @�\\u0001\\u001a�C��\\u0000�O\\u0002\\u0011T�*\\u0019ՠFԀ\\u0006Q\\u000bZ_\'�@��\\u0007=�AF#\\u0018\\u0011� �w\\u001eL`B4C0b��!\\u0010�\\u0018\\n��s\\u0010\\u0006a��\\u0010�\\u0018\\u0001���2FA��/��h�\\u001e�\\u0003�\\u0002VD��6����\\u0018�A��\\u001d1\\u0016�\\u0010� \\u001e1\\u001e�\\u000f�\\t=\\u0011\\u0013 \\u00011\\u0011\\u0012\\u0011{�\\u0003с�;$A\\u0012b2$#��ވNp!� ��\\u001b�Ș\\n��np#��>�i���\\u0015�è\\f�L�D̂,ľ��w\\u0016�A\x7F��0\\u0000q��\\u0003a b6d�~\\u0001\\u000f\\fB\\u001c$c\\u000e� �B.b\\u001e��~�|\\u0018�8\\u0018� \\u000e�q(\\fE\\u001c\\u0006�|?�p\\u0018�X\\u0000#\\u0010G�Hđ2��Q�\\u001fa4�F,�1�c`,�X�\\u001f�\\b�\\u0010��\\u0018q\\u001c�C�\\u0006�#��\\u0012�\\u0019\\\\a(�B)�\\u0004��8\\u0011�E�\\u0016�|��L�I0\\tq2LF,�r�\\n���\\u001e��X\\t��UP�X\\rՈSa��;�\\u00065�52�B-�t��8\\u0003f����P�X\'�,��X\\u000f��^�����Ѐ� c#4\\"6A\\u0013b34���90\\u0007q.�C�\'�|���\\u0000\\u0016�����\\u0010q\\u0011,F\\\\,�\\u0012X��\\u0002-�/�\\u0015Z\\u0011����Ka\\u0019�2\\u0019۠�w\\u0012���\\u0011��r�\\u0015�\\u0012q���`��\\u000bX\\r�\\u0011��\\u001a�\\u001b�F�\\u001b�&ě\\u0010?���f�[�\\u0016ĵ�\\u0016q\\u001d�G\\\\��\\u0019��\\u001b\\u00107�F�[�V�M�\\u0019q3��;\\u0001��x;lA�\\"�\\u001dp\\u0007�V���)�)�]�\\rq��w�݈����O�^؎�]���~��e�\\u0001;|\\u001f�\\u0003� �2\\u0010\\u001f��?�?|\\u001f���\\b�#�(�Ў�.�.���\\u0010v�n�=�\\u0018�c�8��\\u0017q/�\\u0007�\\u000f�!�\\u0003�\\u0007� �Ax\\u0002�\\t���\\u0010\\u001cB<\\f�\\u0011����OB\\u0007b\\u0007<�{\\u000f���ix\\u001a�\\u0019x\\u0016�Yx\\u000e�9�w�yx\\u001e�\\u0005x\\u0001�Ex\\u0011�%x\\u0019�ex��\\u000e�\\u0002�\\"�*�k�\\u001a�Qx\\u001d�ux��6�!�18��&��x\\u001c�#�\\u0005o���\\u001dx\\u0017�]\\u0019߃�\\u0010߇\\u000f|��\\u0003�\\u0010�C�\\b�#\\u0019?��\\u0011?�O|o§p\\u0002�爟��\\u0005|�;\\u0006\'�K�/�+į�kįe�\\u0006��\\u0001�·�������x\\nN!��Ӿ��\\f�A�\\u0001~D�\\u0011~B�\\t~F�\\u0019�(�\\u0002� ������o���#�\\u0006\x7F�\\u001f�\x7F\x9F�\x7F�9�sp��*��N�N�\\u0010%\\u0019}���wML�5�\\u0019X\\u001a\\"\\u0011x)��u\\u001aa\\u0018�~�vaM�¼\\u001cTk���b�\\u001d�\\u0010�3!�\\u0017j��NW\\n�ʹ�Lԉ�\\u0004�#/\x7F�Æ\\u0017�\\u0000\\u0018]8fl\\u0011��f|\\tL�xm\\u0019�7��w^\\u0012e�P�Ɏ\x7F[\\u000b��\\u0005H�\\u0015C\\u001a�\\u0018\\\\/�QS\\u000fA�;\\n��8Ԙ\\u0013P�yQ\\u000b-�y�\\u0013g��s��\\u0007 �N�K�b�\\u0002,=V.]�z�\\u00015UWi\\u001c\\u0002�\\u0017������I���p�Kځ=Fg\\u0018�&{ܓS:��h��\\u0011Æff���q�������\\u001c�\\u0012\\u0013z����clVK��Ȉ�А`�)�h��\\u001a�J\\u0014�\\n�c\\u0019\\u0002I�=,�dW��\\u0011i��J�\\u0003�K��l��g[;\\u0004]R(.�G_\\u0016��\\u001d\\u001f�\\u000e�����<Z�.\\u0018�U;�ډ�\\u001dh+�4\\u0012[\\n<�_5ݞ_�\\u001e�[U^�O��\\r���?:\\u0003��u�R�r��ժ�$إRcP�!,��E\\u0006\\u000f$r�\\u0019��w\\u0017\\u0003�69�=������kz�gM9\\u0006�yX\\u0013�.���u�pq\\u0016�c]!�?D�\\u0015��J�]km���\\u001d�Xw%u��a�\\u0001��;4U���k�s\\u0015H�.`��k�)\\u001f��U^cm�r\\u0019\\"1Ś_c]m��ȯ)G���SWL��ܒ\\u0015���� ��\\u001b\\u001d�C�Đ\\u0005\'#���a�V\\u001a]�z��}ۘ��sm\\u0014KKKÐ���v�\\u0010+˟��]\\ts&\'��\\u0014`@U�t���\\nJg�t��5�2�7�4�E�kp`*�]�ի���U\\u0015U9��s�=��\\r�\'��\\u001dD��\\u0006�\\u0002\\u00050��s��Jm~f\\u0017�-ɥ��+�\\"��ޝR\\u001eH����L+�`\\u0018V�n�����\\u0012;\\u0016ͤP�\\t�+3e᱕\\u0012|���S�|��n]�+��r��S��T\\u0004R\\u0014q�_�\\u0006\\u0007�\\u0007��^=�n\\u001d��|u�~_�\\u0014��`_���`�7�\\u001c[-,����\\u000e��l\\u001f|Ci�����E�S\\t\\u0018<�$;�f,�\\u0016vE\\u0001E\\n\\u0005K-w\\u0007��?�\\u00027�2\\u0014�جȨq%��ȧ\\u0012\\u001a.ư�N\\u0005\\t\\u00057\\u0013�8�6ʣ��n��\\u0006�6\\u001b��5�=0\\u0005#��cJ�q+L��\\r\\u001e�\\u0003ǣ��tt�\\u0004��9�]9ݏ�۱��d\\u0005\\u0016�.�w��\\r!�����$�_dW���M�%l$S�\\u000f1�,\\r�\\u001c8����:0��X�������h�K:\\"��Z\\rF�\\u0000t��\\u0005c&�X�WwK�?%�S*\\u0007(����Ձ�D���2�`+(�0�8M�:���?>�Kqa����ǻ�\\u0005A\\u0001)(F)G=���NV���!+�&�\\u001c�5Ժ��d7C����]��Wr�\\n��S\\u0019�J\\u0013i�J#���\\u0018\\u0011��\\u0007<\\u0000�r.\'\'����\\u0004�4�+�@�~Ɵf�7\\u0014/7��E�r?���t��0M��i�\\u000bhw=*�#xD���2��\\bMڍ)\\u0007q\\u0018E\\u0002{4DK\\"w�Sc����u����h�\\u0012\\u001e?�+�]hz܄�=\\u001a��dĆr��\'�\\u0006YYb��[��=�%�JkV��R\\u001d��2��P�Xb�\\u001bڭ\\u0011/E�6|Y�\\f��X<DVA/\\u0012\\u0005�H���|�A�$\\u000eRI,�cѫU��\\u000e6�\\u001e��\\u0003\\u000b�\\u0010H/\\r�W�\\n��,d<\\f%�`�\\u001a\x7F:��\\"+\x7F K0�\\u0018�80e\\u0011Y�+��,ĸ\\u0011�\\u000b\\u0002���<�D-d\\u001eƣ�>7p�C&�m6�\\u0006�ހ��x�\\u001dh�\\u001b��\\u0007�3\\u0003�3\\u0002��{m�^\\u0013�W��\\u0019-�Ie��)�bw�ų���1���}�Ɛ>HG�\\u0003tL\\u000e�\'��\\u000eR�GkH�\'1�~?\\u0019�}4a�G�6�,����z��\\u0010\\u0019��-��D\x7Fj\\u0002M�O�w��M���7�n��Bi�!\\"\\u0006x*�3��̈�!438Ј�_��߈\\u0002S9L�w\\u0013��y��|�u��믌\\u0016Tb��w�/��ɻ댖��z\\u0015�W�z\\u0019���z\\n�\\u0007��Z����-V�m[\\u0012,[�EZ~�\\u001clٱ9ܲis/˭��,\\u001b1��L6cq��dúp��u\\u000e��u6\\u000b�#��kש\\r��C�C�C��\\t\\u0002\\u0007\\f\\u0007\\u0018=ήǉ���?\\u0018����=��-�\\u0012�Y�Y�z��\\f�<�}j�)����mf��\\u0004��=F�sO���vo��-�˓��/�r��\\r�y\\u001a;B\\u001b�=��7[z[���F���z��ҁדx�|�w��\\u001f&��dףF��Qbx��\\u0000�f�˲z�Ӳ��mY�\\u0016fY���a��ی�em}-mXM��m;�w�����M\\f�Z��\\\\���5.m\\t�\\\\�2�Ҋ�%��b�\\n[�[�-�Ao��\\u0004��(\\u00156KxX/\\u000b��,��^��d}/�.!Q\\u001f�S\\u0017\\u001b����6}\\u000f�.2*Z\\u001b\\u0016\\u001e�\\r\\u000e\\t�\\u0006��Z����hu\\u001aQ��(����x\\r�\\u0013\\u001a��U�x\\u0014�\\n�ö��\\u001e�a4��\\u001e�\\u0018�D�c�I��| D�\\u0013,�����\\u0012,�)X\\nݤ=�\\u0000P���P�\\n�r�ݎ\\u0002TQc�S\\u001d\\u0005�b�Ē]��T����J\\u001c��vn%�b��&L,�O�i���Q�!TJ��xcdw���\\u0011�^UPT��.mO��[�K��GcScc��\\u001f�]!����9����T��-ZS��\x7FG����H�ы�� V�\\u001d��\\\\t��YNo�[s�DǤ\x7F$��܅#l�\\u0003\\u0014fP\\u0001���҅��\\u0010�`�w�g2~�\\u0015��|����!\\u0004��/\\u00079�$�\x7F� 7�夕\\u0014�&�#ͨ?=�,K\\u0011�a�\\u001e\\u001e�\\u000b�\\u0007�\\u0012+\\t\':B��\\u0018Qs�#q$��P!�0N�g=+��*�Y�\\u0017~adn�\\u001a�����$z�\\u0012��\\u0011<��\\u0013�;l�\\u0007�I��P8��Ga��a\\u0017\\u001c�2/�3\\u001f�W�#\\u0011�\\u0004\\\\\\u001fV�\\r��\\u000ea&`�0�KV1#�s\\\\,(�\\\\&�Lc\\u000f��DA�q5;\\b��\\u0007l;��mp�Mf��<\\u0018\\u0001�I\\u001f�a�c{�\\u0016�\\u0018sߕ�!�A�,\\u0001;�c�����r��Jr ����|��\\u001b�;i\'��H˥��_:.ȁ�[�)\\u0014�I��R�S�\\u0007+`��e���C�I��z�\\"q\\u0004�$\\nǀ��8\\u0006��q�u�<ZF\\"�\\u0004��\\u0011y�D�!�#g�`y\x7F�W�>P�G8\\u0001_�3\\u001a��#�����\\u001b`�\\u0011�\\u0004\\u0005�6P�y���^��>~M�\\u0014��h3�!\\u0010,�W+\\u000f��\\u001dZ�v\\b\\u0003;�\\u00178��,?��+�,ð\\u0004^׳嬗Ń{\\u001d�\\u0006e��E�)��Gdʜe��xA��\\u0019����\\"�]>9M�����Ka��Ì�\\u0017�\\u0003xJ�b�`\\u000b��ߓ4�\\u00140\\u0005����d����3�\\n���0-�\\u0016�N\\t$R�S�Z��=\\u001eb8K�qCv6�QFl��\\u0010�a\\u000bV(�\\n&�\\u001c\\u0014\\u001a\\u0012\\u0012��Vt\\u001c8�A�Y�ݿ`����\\n����G$\\u0012Ϗ>�\\u001ev`�\\\\��\\u000fI�-���\\u0010J��H��.z�P�{Ly�B��TΔ��r���^�׬\\u000b\\u0002.\\u0012/�q�\\u000e�\\u001bj��\\u0012z\\f�Җ����\\u001e�և�\\u0019\\u001f�3�\\u0016\\u0012�n>�!�(��oం���ǐ�\\u001d\\u0007��җR�g�C:�.\\"!\\u000fm\'1s\\u0017\\u001d\\u0018\\u0016���6\\u001d�ʄp\'�\\u001a#��̞*�\\u001a\\u0019A\\u0010�aB�1QH4�fF��\\u0004�ڣ\\u001bf��L�K�1�1�\\u0012�4�:�\\\\]���7�bf1߬�/6�\\u001bu\\u000b\\f+\\r6�P\\u0000��\\u0018N\x7FBET�J\\u0003`4|�Uӽ\\u0011�Bۮ\\u0011���h(i�eg��\\f�C�\\fx�\\u0001���?�\\u0014W\\u0019vQ\\u0019g����qq\\u0019<�f�By�d�ԡ~[���#�ҝ3I��-�\\f��ng���@�J&�y���;�&\\u0013�����\\u0006�o\\u0016�`k�x��(����\\u0018����1N~4������4�\\u0013哭��s��X�D\\u0018��\\u001e8[�8�\\u001f�U0��\\u0012\\u0018r\\u001d&�*�[��\\fE��@����(V�)�(�(f+U��\\u0003�ދ�\\u0006�H8��_� \\n�\'\\f��.�D^\\u0005<��~ߧ� �!��!�^���ECxg��]�t8ʂB���Mo(�YY�\x7F\\u0010G�H~1,湲RR������!�Ёُe�#E\\u0006��Ge�$65��!5N�|o����\'\\u0007\\u001d���d�8\x7F�|\\u001d\\u0013��\\u001d��i�/�Y�\\u0019p��\\u0003��\\u0019�\\u0011��\x7F7��=�\\u0019\'j2�\\u0003\\u0011��h;\\u001b�%\\nN�\\u0019m��2��xUi�5���\\u0002Q�4e��M-&�d�X��ɮ��do2��\\u001c�\\u0016L���i�6:mr\\u001ak]���\\u0007gV��TȦ\\u0002-\\u0003���A\\u001c\\u000e>&�g<��\'(#=֝\\u001aB��ю�\\u001d\\u001fo��i�\\b6�4w*�}z��H����|��uuu���\\nb�9i�\'�.1)j\\\\zF�1�\\u0006�\\u001b6���[�\\r^�7�82!sj���)\\u0015\\u0015$��.b�V93�hr��Ma9Vk��_֡�7\\u001cJ�p����\\t��\\bO2\\u0004��4��T\\f@i�A4��^�A�\\"����9�|�\\"d����S�\\u0017�`\\u0001\\u0016�o�X<�B\\u000b\\u001bڢ|�\\u0007��2�YTV��٧�P�\\u0019������r�!A|\\u001f�kv��G�\\u0001G��I�ww��D�%\x84�wI�3��-\\\\TQ��u@�\\u0014��7�}%9}�c\\u00032\'IO���X����׆���DG\\u0013��~A*�0�\\u0013!�u)<�r�\\u0017��v\\u0005\\u001e�_˰��D�F��\\u0010�!p��h\\u0015b\\u000by\\\\c��3Ո���tȤ\\u0006Q�C�Muw��~9�\\n��9���s!��?&��|x����ز\\b9\\u001e3�օ\\u000eq9��\\\\I�\\n��e��i\\u0014�\\u0019\\u0000j�z��ax䎊����t��(�]��\\u000bM~�Y�,�^Z�9�]��҉�6l���g�\\u0017(��p�\\u0001���U��w�\\u0013��j�\\u001dJG�=�$�8j*_���/V.\\b�\\u001d��Y���\\u0019;%&K4d��\\"��fk�-ZN�5�\\u0013�����i\\u001f����jmK\\u0000�=�$b1�\\bV�)Xž8�oe�)�(�FJ1J�,�4���� �� [Q�\\u0001\\u001d��$\\u0018��3h��/���ۥ6i,�M��\\u0013ս����}���z\x7FN�04T $-Dz�yt\\\\ϑd+��\\u0013Ƀi��{�GFZ{�\\u001f����ߥ�\\u0018�Ēp��B\\\\���G?�\\u0013#r�\\u0015��]O\\u0004�ݪ\\u0016�g�\\u0006���VcѺ�\\u001e�W�����M5t�M\\u0005ggjvg�<�n�\\u001diC�d�8���Y���Y\\"�O\\u0011A��|v`�\\u0015I�\\u001d��b4�p2�\\u0011D\\rEcpW\\u0018\'\\u0002�;���/�I\\u0013F2�B\\u001dS-,d�tq�\\u000eI\\u0014�V\\u0006U�J��.ͨV�*�W\\u0011��<Z\\"ˌ\\u0001�\\t��\\u0016��\\u0016^\\u0016��,*2e�\\u0018Qh��\\\\a@\\r�wr\\u001d\\u0004��Ё*�j�rN\\u001d�N\\u0014��tu�8��\\u0013�s�*�13�l\\u0015.�ML�Z��*�f�D娉 Z��n�F��R\\u0000���Ũ�jƃ��Q��.�4~�\\u0004�6\\u0012�E2mee~�P\\u001e�\\bt �Tm;(����I��l6��ŝນ$%J�\\u0013�V�ʘ��΃Lq�\\u0014�\\u001f����9�k�������1#�֢�R\\u000e^��F��LV��1�W�����x�(V��?v��\\u000eŻX�\\u0006�=\\u0000*�\\u001b83\\rd\\u0014����Ҿ���<tf�#�\\u000e5\\u000b�F�W\\u001b�('... 702140 more characters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set in your response the correct mimetype: application/pdf

instead of using

```js
response ={
    statusCode:200,
    body: doc
}
```

use this one:

```js
response ={
    statusCode:200,
    headers: {"content-type": "application/pdf"},
    body: doc
}
```

This should give your browser the information, of the correct content type.

Edit:
if this won't work, you probably need to follow this instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added the content type as suggested but I still get the same results with the blob encryption on the page

Comment: Just edited my post, after searching one sample project of mine where I referenced to that link I just added.

Comment: I'm almost there. I had a typo in my script. Once I fixed that, add the header you suggested finally triggered the download but the file is coming through corrupted. I tried add `isBase64Encoded: true` to the response object but that resulted in an internal error.

If I remove the `JSON.stringify` statement around `doc` I can open the PDF w/o errors but its blank